# MS Word - Default save as type is web page

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I am generating a word document programmatically using c# language. The document is generated properly in .doc format, but when I try to use *save as* option for this document, it shows web page options as default selected option. I want .doc or .docx option as default save as type for this document. In other documents it is showing .doc as default save as type which is proper.

I am generating the document using below code:

```
var loMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var loFileStream = new FileStream(lsHtmlFileFullPath, FileMode.Open))
{
    await loFileStream.CopyToAsync(loMemoryStream);
}
loMemoryStream.Position = 0;

FileStreamResult loInputFileStream = File(loMemoryStream, "application/vnd.ms-word", Path.GetFileName(lsDocFileFullPath));

using (System.IO.FileStream loOutputFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(lsDocFileFullPath, FileMode.Create))
{
    loInputFileStream.FileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    loInputFileStream.FileStream.CopyTo(loOutputFileStream);
    loInputFileStream.FileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
}
```

How can I get .doc or .docx file format as default save as type programmatically?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the content of lsHtmlFileFullPath?

Comment: It contains word doc content in Html format.

Comment: If it's a HTML file, Word will obviously offer you to save in HTML format. Why would you expect Word to offer different format that will change the formatting? Let me guess, you don't actually create a .doc, if your ".doc" file is opened in Notepad, is there HTML tags all over? Then it's just Word being courteous accepting a file in different format, just like HTML files containing tables can be opened in (at least the Windows desktop version of) Excel if you change it's extension to xls, but at no point did you create/converted an actual .doc file

Comment: Since a Word document is either a proprietary binary file (old *.doc file format) OR an Open XML ZIP package (new *.docx file format) it's not possible to create a "real" Word document using the code shown, as Martheen says in that comment. In order to create a file that Word recognizes as a "real" Word document, look into Open Office XML (SDK), especially the "altChunk" functionality that allows inserting a non-Word file type (such as HTML) that Word will convert to native Word content when the file is opened. That would work around the behavior problem you're seeing.